# Counting the number of rational points on a curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be the curve defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ by the equation
$$
(x+1)^2 (x^2 + 1) = (y+1)^2 (y^2 + 1)
$$
I would like to know how many $(x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_p^2$ satisfy this equation.
I am wondering if there are any clever ways to compute the number of these points. Any suggestions is appreciated! thank you

ps I tried to use Hasse-Weil but I am struggling to figure out whether this curve satisfies the conditions....

Comment: Have you tried to compute this number for small values of $p$?

Comment: Your curve seems to be reducible. Letting $f = (x+1)^2 (x^2 + 1) - (y+1)^2 (y^2 + 1)$, then $f = (x-y)(x^3 + x^2 y + 2 x^2 + x y^2 + 2 x y + 2 x + y^3 + 2 y^2 + 2 y + 2)$.

Comment: I suspect (after counting points in $\mathbb F_p$ for various $p$) that the second factor has genus $1$, and so its number of points is bounded between $p\pm 2\sqrt p$.

Comment: If you're happy with an esay, very rough estimate: for every $x$, $(x,x)$ is on the curve, so there are at least $p$ points; for any given $x$, it's a fourth degree equation in $y$, so it has at most four solutions, hence, there are at most $4p$ points.

Comment: "esay" was, of course, a typo for "easy".

Comment: Thank you for the many comments!

Comment: @ViktorVaughn and for the inclusion-exclusion, the intersection is $2(x + 1)(2x^2 + x + 1)$ so has 1 or 3 points depending on if $-7$ is a square (or $2$ points if $p = 2, 7$).